# How to fix Uncaught ReferenceError: lava is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I'm using lavacharts in my Laravel project to draw a LineChart I did all the installation commands as  recommended in their site http://lavacharts.com/#faq-format-cell but I always cause this error : Uncaught ReferenceError: lava is not defined .

Comment: I created a new project with the same version of laravel i did the same work as my project it works here .i don't know whre is the problem in my current project.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Facade` installation method. Add the following code to your `config/app.php` file:

```
"aliases" => [
    ...

    'Lava' => 'Khill\Lavacharts\Laravel\LavachartsFacade',
]
```

Then make sure you are using `Lava::DataTable()` insteald of `$lava->DataTable();`. It looks like you're trying to use the library in `manual` setup instead of the `Laravel` setup outlined in the documentation (http://lavacharts.com/#faq-format-cell)

Comment: i really did all that and still have the same problem.

Comment: normmaly the  Lava::render('LineChart', 'Temps', 'temps_div') function  generate  two javascripts i but mine it generate just one

Comment: can you share a `Gist` of your `config/app.php` file please? I'm not sure the Facade is setup correctly

Answer (score -1):

make sure you have installed correct version of lavacharts that supports your Laravel version.

add below lines only to your config/app.php

```
 <?php
    // config/app.php

    // ...
    'providers' => [
    // ...

    Khill\Lavacharts\Laravel\LavachartsServiceProvider::class,
   ],

    // ...
    'aliases' => [
    // ...

    'Lava' => Khill\Lavacharts\Laravel\LavachartsFacade::class,
    ]
```

Comment: my laravel version is 5.4 and lavacharts is 3.1